# raise idle event

Tags: c#

i want to raise application.idle event manually in a Loop. is it possible in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't raise the Application.Idle event manualy.

If your goal is to continue processing messages while in a loop, you can call Application.DoEvents() every so often during the course of the loop, but this will not cause the Application.Idle event to be raised.

If you need to process the Idle event while in a loop, you can run your loop on a background thread, which will keep the UI responsive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The Application.Idle event is raised by the RaiseIdle() method.  You cannot call this yourself directly, it is a private method.  Technically you can use Reflection to work around that.

This however isn't likely to work out well, Idle has a very specific meaning.  It is raised when the message loop has dispatched all pending messages and no more work needs to be done.  Raising idle in a loop doesn't make sense, you're not idle, you're looping.  Any action taken by the app in their Idle event handlers isn't going to have a noticeable effect on the UI.  For that matter, raising it in a loop doesn't make sense either, an app cannot be idle more than once.

When you contemplate writing code like this you probably are really looking for Application.DoEvents().